# Are there any differences between MS Edge running on ubuntu or windows for End-to-end testing?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, microsoft-edge, end-to-end, playwright

I'm setting up a e2e test stack with ms Playwright.
It should run in a ci pipeline. Playwright comes with a docker image:  `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal`
which is bases on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
I have noticed Edge is not included in the image. Edge (running on windows) is the primaire browser that we have to use for our e2e suit. Basically I want to install edge in the image: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/
My question is: Has anybody experienced differences between running Edge on ubuntu and windows 10 which may impact e2e testing/ user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Edge for Linux is still in insider preview, and it's not recommended to use in the production environment.

For now, you can raise a feature request about your issue here: [Share your feedback about Microsoft Edge on Linux (Enterprise) - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/share-your-feedback-about-microsoft-edge-on-linux-enterprise/m-p/2381414)